# how to execute code in server from browser

Tags: turtle-graphics, vnc, replit

This is a question out of curiosity.

Does anybody know how repl.it is executing python code in a virtual desktop environment (especially turtle code)?

We have an application hosted in AWS, can Amazon workspaces be handy for the purpose?

Came to know that repl.it uses x11-vnc for the purpose, any clue on how this is implemented?

Comment: Running code sent from the client in the server is a **SERIOUS** vulnerability, never do that. Playground and other test environments often use a specially isolated server environment (or even an emulator) to simulate execution, it's rarely, if ever, run in an actual server, specially outside of highly trusted environments.

Comment: I understand, but this is a special case where in we have a python IDE inside our application that uses skulpt.js to execute python code on the browser itself. But skulpt does not have full support for python turtle graphics. That is why thought of executing it on an isolated server and stream the result to the browser. I have seen repl.it doing this (I am not sure how exactly they achieve this), so thought of knowing more about it